# Prime elements and irreducible elements of quotient rings of polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

We know that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a euclidean domain hence prime elements and irreducible elements are the same. Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $R=\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x))$. Let $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[x]\longrightarrow R$, $\phi:g(x)\longmapsto g(x)+(f(x))$.

> (1) If $g(x)$ is prime in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, will $\phi(g(x))$ be prime in $R$?
>
> (2) If $g(x)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, will $\phi(g(x))$ be irreducible in $R$?
>
> (3) Can we put any conditions on $f(x)$ such that (1), (2) are true?
>
> (4) What will happen in the case $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f(x_1,\dots,x_n))$?
>
> (5) How about $\mathbb{Q}[x]/(f(x))$ and $\mathbb{Q}[x_1,\dots,x_n]/(f(x_1,\dots,x_n))$?

Are there any chapters or theorems about these questions? I am confused on these questions.

Comment: $\Bbb Z[x]$ is *not* a Euclidean domain. It's not even a PID. It is, however, a UFD.

Comment: (following up the comment of @AymanHourieh) so indeed in the UFD $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ primes and irreducibles are the same.

Comment: Wait, you assume $R$ to be an integral domain, right?

Answer (score 2):

There are some trivial cases for (1) and (2), such as $g$ is mapped to zero, or to a unit.

Among the non-trivial examples, $2$ is prime and irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but not in the Euclidean domain $\mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^{2} + 1)$.

A variation on this yields examples for (4).